# MongoDB aggregation, nodejs generate dynamic query with AND & OR

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have query with aggregation for MongoDB in my nodejs code.

```
const query = {
  '$expr':{
    '$and':[
      {'$eq': ['$appId', req.user.appId]},
    ]
  }
}
```

From the frontend, a filter object is received, as follows:

```
{
  shops: '604c776763c302032e610347',
  offset: '0',
  limit: '20',
}
```

I need dynamically push shops id in my query. need to be **appId** -> *user.appID* **AND** **targetFrom || targetTo** <- shops(*from the filter object*)

shops can be **one id** or **array of ids**, for this I'm using `$in` operator

```
query['$expr']['$and'].push({
  $eq: [
    {
      $or: [
        {"targetFrom": {$in: bb}},
        {"targetTo": {$in: bb}}
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

The old version of code was as follows:

```
const query = {
  $and: [
    {appId: req.user.appId}
  ]
}

query['$and'].push({
  $or: [
    {"targetFrom": {$in: bb}}, <- in bb is mongodb objectID
    {"targetTo": {$in: bb}}
  ]
})
```

#### Update

How I can search some `item` by ID in my `items` array of objects?

```
if(req.query.products) {
  typeof req.query.products === 'string' ? req.query.products = [req.query.products] : req.query.products
  let bb = req.query.products.map(function(el) { return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(el) })
  query['$expr']['$and'].push({
    $and: [
      {
        items: {
          $in: ['item.itemId', bb]
        }
       }
     ]
   })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see if the following addresses your requirement:

[Mongoplayground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ISQyvMa_vAU)

#### Assumptions:

1. `req.user.appId` is a string.
2. `bb` is an array of either objectIds or strings (`[ObjectId("asdfsd"),ObjectId("badsfds")]`, etc.)

```
const query = {
  "$expr": {
      $and: [{
        "$eq": ["$appId",req.user.appId],
      }]
      
  }
}

query['$expr']['$and'].push({
  $or: [
    {
      $in: [
        "$targetFrom",
        bb
      ]
    },
    {
      $in: [
        "$targetTo",
        bb
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

---

##### Edit: Requirement is updated: Fetch all objs with a particular `appId`, where either `targetFrom` or `targetTo` is one of a given array, and `date` is between given `startDate` and `endDate`:

[Monogplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qrd0Z2Gf03Z)

In the above mongoplayground, I'm fetching all the objects where `appId` is "1", `startDate` is `2022-01-01`, `endDate` is `2022-01-31` and bb is  ["a","c","x"]. This should fetch all 3 docs, but the date filters out the third doc, because the `date` in that doc is `2021-12-24`. If you change the date before that, you'll get all 3.

```
const query = {
  "$expr": {
      $and: [{
        "$eq": ["$appId",req.user.appId],
      }]

  }
}

query['$expr']['$and'] = query['$expr']['$and'].concat([{
          $and: [
            {
              $gte: [
                "$date",
                startDate
              ]
            },
            {
              $lt: [
                "$date",
                endDate
              ]
            }
          ]
        },{
  $or: [
    {
      $in: [
        "$targetFrom",
        bb
      ]
    },
    {
      $in: [
        "$targetTo",
        bb
      ]
    }
  ]
}])
```

#### Edit: Requirement updated: need to add `items.id` filter.

[Mongoplayground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vceV0Zb1I0j)

IF you want to filter documents out if no object in `items` has the given id, just add the extra object I added in the `$and` array in the `$match stage`.

```
{
 $in: [
       1,
       "$items.id",
 ]
}
```

IF you don't want to filter out such documents, but want to filter out all objects in `items` where the `items.id` is NOT the given ID, the only solution I could find is using a `$project` stage, added in the new mongoplayground link.

Comment: maybe you can help me with this one?)
query.date = {
                    $gte: startDate,
                    $lt: endDate
                }

                query['$and'].push({
                    $or: [
                        {"date": {$gte: startDate, $lt: endDate}},
                    ]
                })

Comment: In your database, is `date` a string (ISOdateString) or a date object?

Comment: it is ISOdateString

Comment: What is an `ISOdateString`? Either it is a `Date` object (where MongoDB provides an alias called `ISODate`) or a `String` - nothing else.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: in mongodb is: "date" : ISODate("2022-01-05T00:00:01.000Z"),
in code: 
const startDate = moment(req.query.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').startOf('day').toDate()

                const endDate = moment(req.query.endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('day').toDate()
so, it is ISODate

Comment: @Bob pls see edit

Comment: thank you again! i'm using if condition like if(req.query.startDate) {...}
and pushing  data in to query without concat

Comment: @Anuj Pancholi probably you can help me with my last question. please, check my update. thank you

Comment: @Mike instead of `array1=array1.concat(array2)` you can just do `array1.push(...array2)`. Also, if you're dynamically constructing a query from `req.query` or `req.body`, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70720917/6718353).
@Bob I'll look into it.